# Passenger + Nginx + Sinatra: friendly error page does not appear

Tags: ruby, nginx, sinatra, passenger

Just installed Ruby by RVM and Passender: gem install passenger && rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module

Simple Sinatra app works fine:

```
app.rb:

require 'sinatra'
get '/' do
  "Hello World!"
end

config.ru:

require 'sinatra'
require './app.rb'
run Sinatra::Application
```

But when I add error in code, for example:

```
require 'sinatra'
get '/' do
  aaa # error here
  "Hello World!"
end
```

I exect to see purple friendly error page, but I see just: **Internal Server Error** if passenger_app_env production in nginx.conf, or standart **An error occurred** nginx error page if production passenger_app_env development.
In both cases there is an error message in error.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked here https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/963 and got the answer.
It works now!

> The fix is already in master branch. Until a new release is made, you can point the gem to master:
>
> ```
> # Gemfile
> gem 'sinatra', github: 'sinatra/sinatra'
> ```